# Apache not able to load stylesheets and scripts in Django's static directory

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am developing a site using Django. Up until now, when I have used it in a developement environment it was working fine, loading all stylesheets and scripts normally. However, I have currently shifted over to a production environment using Apache Web Server with mod_wsgi for serving Django pages. Now when I am viewing the site, it is reporting that the css and js files couldn't be loaded and were returned with an error code 403 - Access Denied. My web site is the directory `"C:\Users\rohitm\Web Applications\WebApp"`. I have installed Apache 2.2 at `"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2"`. I have edited the httpd.conf file under the conf sub-directory in the Apache installation folder as follows:

```
Alias /static/ "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static"
<Directory "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/images/ "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/images"
<Directory "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/images">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/javascript/ "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/javascript"
<Directory "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/javascript">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/stylesheets/ "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/stylesheets"
<Directory "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/stylesheets">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /static/admin/ "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/admin"
<Directory "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/admin">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/apache/django.wsgi"
<Directory "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/apache">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have created a file django.wsgi in a folder apache under my WebApp folder. The contents are as follows:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/')
sys.path.append('C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'WebApp.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The static files settings in settings.py are as follows

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'
```

After running the `manage.py collectstaic` command, the static folder has 4 sub folders - `admin`, `images`, `stylesheets` and `javascript`. The stylesheet folder contains a file `main.css` while the javascipt folder contains a file `jquery.min.js`. The admin folder has all the admin related css and js present there. Now whenever I am viewing the site via `http://localhost`, the css and javascript files are not loaded, while the browser console (Chrome - Crtl+Shift+J) reports that the files failed to load as the server responded with an error 403 (Forbidden).

Please help urgenty.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the trailing slash on first path given to Alias directive, or alternatively add a trailing slash to second path. The use of trailing slash should be balanced, ie., not on either, or on both.

You also only need the Alias/Directory block for the top directory where static files are. You don't need to enumerate it for all the sub directories. Thus use:

```
Alias /static "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static"
<Directory "C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Note now that using '/static' and not '/static/'.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the user that Apache is running under does not have access to the `C:/Users/rohitm/Web Applications/WebApp/static` folder.

In general, it's probably best to put those files somewhere central, rather than in your personal home directory.